# Stream HLS (Android) to DLNA clients on LAN

Tags: android, stream, http-live-streaming, dlna

Currently, I want to stream a movie which are TS files in a m3u8 playlist format from my Android smartphone to on-LAN DLNA supported clients (such as my Samsung TV).

I had search but could not find any good starting point.

Any helps would be appreciated!